# 1/st Stage slow down after MECO and separation for F9's

Tags: spacex, stages, stage-separation

Once the Falcon 9 Full Thrust 1st Stage reaches "MECO" - main engine cut off - and separates from the 2nd Stage how much velocity does it lose?  Specifically at "MECO" its velocity is approx. 5,900 km/hr  Does the 2nd Stage separation "push off" from the 1st Stage significantly slow down the 1st Stage before the 1st Stage engines ignite for the boost back burn?

Answer (score 3):

No, only a very small amount of speed is lost. I'm not sure exactly what it is, but no more then a few miles/hour. Otherwise you would see the two separate much faster.